# Why is there such a thing as an id if you can just have classes with only one element?

Tags: html, markup

From a language-design standpoint, what's the point of creating the id attribute for HTML if you can have a class with only one element?  Why not just use classes for everything and not complicate the markup?

I can think of three possible explanations, but they don't fully satisfy me, so I wondered if you know why id was included in HTML.  My thoughts are:

1. The existence of an id helps in creating CSS styles because its greater specificity makes it possible to give an id to one member of a class overriding styles given to other members of that class.  This explanation doesn't fully satisfy me because you could just give it an extra class instead and put the styles for that class at the bottom of the stylesheet in a section for styles given to single elements.
2. When selecting elements with jQuery, the DOM traversal could stop as soon as the element with that id is found.  Thus, the existence of an id would make the selection run faster.  This explanation doesn't satisfy me because I'm fairly certain that jQuery was created long after ids and classes already existed.
3. Having an id as a language feature could help to ensure that styles (and selectors) which are supposed to be unique truly are applied to only one element because things go haywire when this isn't the case.  This explanation doesn't satisfy me because having your site break when you accidentally create two elements with the same id doesn't seem to be a particularly effective way of informing you that something's gone wrong.

Comment: CSS isn't the only thing for which ids are used.

Comment: Closed?  It says it was closed because "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise."  Surely there must be someone on this site who was a part of the original specification of HTML back in the mid nineties or who has read about its creation.  That would be `specific expertise` relevant to the question and could use as `references` the original W3C specification documents or meeting minutes.  Why was this closed?

Comment: Why are there *unique constraints* in SQL when only adding a particular (but arbitrary) value "just once" still provides uniqueness?

Comment: @user166390 There are no unique constraints in an HTML document, an ID in HTML is the equivalent of naming a column "id" and then not adding a unique constraint.

Comment: @3nafish I suspect that if you follow the version history of HTML and then CSS you will find that the ID selector was proposed and part of the earliest versions of HTML before CSS and/or the class attribute was implemented as a standard. Although 'class' can be used as a element identifier just as 'id' can its most likely survived HTML versions because it still allows for easier semantic markup and backwards compatibility. either way 'class' was an attribute added to the standards long after `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first publicly available description of HTML was a document called "HTML Tags", first mentioned on the Internet by Berners-Lee in late 1991](http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html).

There is a description of anchor tag:

```
<A NAME=xxx HREF=XXX> ... </A>

HREF
...This allows for the form HREF=#identifier to
refer to another anchor in the same document.
NAME
The attribute NAME allows the anchor to be the destination of a link.
```

I think NAME attribute here is the predecessor of element's ID: it allowed you to link directly to a desired part of a hypertext page (even if it is the same page).

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  I hadn't considered the capacity of ids to link within a page.  I wonder if that's their origin. +1

Answer (score 3):

IDs are [unique values](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) so, when you parse the html with something such as javascript, you can be sure of what element your script will hit.

Answer (score 2):

For Javascript anyway `getElementById` is a few times faster than `getElementsByClassName`

```
Test                   Ops/sec
getElementById         269,235
getElementsByClassName  86,369
```

[`ref`](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-getelementsbyclassname/8)

More info from the spec

> What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can 
>   have the same value in a conformant document, regardless of the type of the 
>   elements that carry them; whatever the document language, an ID typed 
>   attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element.

So it is a way to uniquely identify an element, where the class selector could only do so by coincidence.

[`ref`](http://w3.org/TR/selectors)

Comment: Yes, but that's already essentially covered by my explanation #2.  Is there any evidence that the language designers took that into account back when they first decided to incorporate the id attribute into HTML?

Comment: You mean where you added "the ID selector stops after the first match"?  How is that any different from possible explanation #2 in my question post where I say "the DOM traversal could stop as soon as the element with that id is found"?

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone knows why the language was designed that way. Repeating back my question as an "answer" without evidence demonstrates nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a great many reasons, most of which don't even involve CSS. For example, ajax and JS libraries often require unique IDs, and IDs can act as anchors with URL hashes.

Answer (score 0):

XML is derived from HTML, but used for more generic data. In XML it is very often desirable to have a unique id (the same way it is often necessary in a database). Because XML puts a lot of effort into automated verifiability, the best approach was to simply add the id attribute as a language element. This way, a XML verifier can output an error if the same value is assigned to two id attributes.

Later, many XML features found their way back to HTML, and I guess id is just one of them. It is not strictly needed, but a nice thing to have in combination with Java Script.

Comment: XML is most *not* derived from HTML. While the syntax (e.g. angle brackets) is similar, it would be more accurate to say "XML was influenced by SGML syntax and concepts".